# Precedence of .then() over code outside a Promise?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Suppose we have a Promise in an asynchronous function:

```
(async function() {

  let x = 0;

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000)
  })
  .then(res => {
    x = 100;
  })

  console.log(x);
})();
```

The console output is always `100`, and never `0`. I tried it in all major browsers and Node.js. This is exactly what I intended to see, but I sense code smell around it. I'm not sure if this is a safe way to pass a value to `x`. It seems to work though, even if I put a lot of code before it. Unless it's something asynchronous (like another `setTimeout()`) it's all good.

**Can someone please confirm if the `.then()` branch actually takes precedence and runs before the `alert(x)` line, or is it happening only by chance?**

(Yes, I know there are better ways to do this, but this is a simplified proof-of-concept snippet.)

Comment: The one promise you are really `await`ing for is the one returned by `.then()`. There is no "precedence" here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s guaranteed because the `await` blocks until the promise chain completes. This is because the `.then` chained to the original promise returns a *new* promise, and the `await` operates on that.

The expected behavior is that the console.log occurs ~2s from the time the function starts running (when the promise is resolved), after x is already assigned (as part of the promise chain).

For “code smell” — I would argue it is *cleaner* to return state from promises and avoid side-effects. However, given the limited scope and guaranteed execution ordering..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this method is "safe". You explicitly `await` the Promise that the .then() code block returns. If your Promise rejects though (failed network request for example) then your code will break, so make sure to add a .catch(error) to the end.

Btw, a more concise way of writing this code would be like this:

```js
(async function() {
  let x = 0;

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000)
  });

  x = 100;
  console.log(x);
})();
```

If you don't need a return value from the Promise, this code acts exactly the same way as yours.

EDIT:
Since the Promise SHOULD indeed provide the value, you can rewrite it like to:

```js
(async function() {
  let x = 0;

  const res = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(100), 2000)
  });

  x = res;
  console.log(x);
})();
```

Comment: True, this is more concise, but the idea is that the Promise should supply the value of x. In your code it's merely a delay.